# After submit, PowerApps field blank when viewing/editing

Tags: list, powerapps-forms, formula, button

I am kind of new to PowerApps and will try to explain my situation below.

I have a field that is being populated on button click. The way I did this was to put `VarFormStatus` under text for the field value, then `OnClick` of the Submit button I have:

```
UpdateContext({varFormStatus: "Contracts"});Reset(Status); SubmitForm(SharePointForm1)
```

I then have another button that is set to visible:

```
If(Status.Text = "Contracts", true, false)
```

After I submit I see that "Contracts" did save in the Status field because it shows up in my SharePoint list. The problem is, when I go back into the form, the button that is supposed to appear is still hidden. Then when I look at the form, Contracts is not showing up in the Status field. If I hit submit again, it all works and if reopen the form without refreshing the screen everything works as it should.

It looks like refreshing the page is what is making "Contracts" disappear from the Power Apps form. Any help would be greatly appreciated in this, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices to do :

1. Either you apply for each new load for the new form the following function :

   OnVisible : NewForm('YourFormName')
2. Either you apply OnSuccess Property of your form the following function :

   Reset('YourFormName')

Comment: Neither of those worked.  For option 1 it says "Behavior function is a non-behavior property. You cant use this property to change values elsewhere in the app".  For option 2 it says "The function expects a resettable control as its input".